# MVC Model is using values for old table entries, but new entries return NULL

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model

I have an interesting little problem. My controller is assigning values to the properties in my model using two tables. In one of the tables, I have some entries that I made a while ago, and also some that I've just added recently. The old entries are being assigned values correctly, but the new entries assign NULL even though they're in the ***same*** table and were created in the same fashion.

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult VerifyReservationInfo(RoomDataView model)
    {

        string loginName = User.Identity.Name;
        UserManager UM = new UserManager();
        UserProfileView UPV = UM.GetUserProfile(UM.GetUserID(loginName));

        RoomAndReservationModel RoomResModel = new RoomAndReservationModel();
        List<RoomProfileView> RoomsSelectedList = new List<RoomProfileView>();

        GetSelectedRooms(model, RoomsSelectedList);

        RoomResModel.RoomResRmProfile = RoomsSelectedList;
        RoomResModel.GuestId = UPV.SYSUserID;
        RoomResModel.FirstName = UPV.FirstName;
        RoomResModel.LastName = UPV.LastName;
        RoomResModel.PhoneNumber = UPV.PhoneNumber;

        return View(RoomResModel);

    }
```

**GetUserProfile from the manager**

```
    public UserProfileView GetUserProfile(int userID)
    {
        UserProfileView UPV = new UserProfileView();
        ResortDBEntities db = new ResortDBEntities();
        {
            var user = db.SYSUsers.Find(userID);
            if (user != null)
            {
                UPV.SYSUserID = user.SYSUserID;
                UPV.LoginName = user.LoginName;
                UPV.Password = user.PasswordEncryptedText;

                var SUP = db.SYSUserProfiles.Find(userID);
                if (SUP != null)
                {
                    UPV.FirstName = SUP.FirstName;
                    UPV.LastName = SUP.LastName;
                    UPV.PhoneNumber = SUP.PhoneNumber;
                    UPV.Gender = SUP.Gender;
                }

                var SUR = db.SYSUserRoles.Find(userID);
                if (SUR != null)
                {
                    UPV.LOOKUPRoleID = SUR.LOOKUPRoleID;
                    UPV.RoleName = SUR.LOOKUPRole.RoleName;
                    UPV.IsRoleActive = SUR.IsActive;
                }
            }
        }
        return UPV;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your code need to be in the question (not links to images of it)

Comment: I can't show the table then, can I?

Comment: Downvote because I tried to post pictures to explain my problem better? That's nice.

Comment: No problem including images, but your code needs to be in the question

Comment: OK, I understand. I'll do that in the future. Edited the code here and I'll add a link to the table screenshot just to clarify. Thanks for the info and the core removal.

Comment: What do you mean they are `null` - your last record is (with `SysUserProfileID = 19`) has no `null` values

Comment: Right, but the controller uses NULL for that last entry(System ID 28), but uses the correct values for the earlier entries. Maybe it has something to do with the call to UserManager that I'm not seeing. I'll edit the post with that in a moment, too. A couple screenshots (sorry!) showing the breakpoint for id 8 and 28: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/L2poFkW.png) [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/eYxjlCO.png)

Comment: What exactly is null? Is `var user = db.SYSUsers.Find(userID);` user here returning null? Or the properties of `user` are null?

Comment: The problem I see here is that you have two `ID` columns, and that last entry has a different value in each.

Comment: Why don't you simply debug your code and check if these `Find(userID)` calls actually return anything?

Comment: @EBrown So embarrassed. If it were a snake, as the saying goes. During debugging, it was returning the correct value for the SYSUserID table as shown in the comment image above, but when finding that value in the SYSUserProfiles table, the primary key was set to the SYSUserProfileID instead of SYSUserId. Thanks for helping me work through the blunder. If you post it as an answer, I'll be happy to mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I see is that this database has a somewhat poor design, and *that particular record* fell into the trap of that poor design. Consider that you have two ID's on that table:

```
SYSUserProfileID
SYSUserID
```

That's usually an indication of a bad design (though I'm not sure you can change it), if you can, you should merge anything that uses `SYSUserID` to use `SYSUserProfileID`.

This is bad because that last row has *two* different ID's. When you use `db.Find(someId)` Entity Framework will look for the Primary Key (`SYSUserProfileID` in this case) which is `19` for that row. But by the sounds of it, you also need to find it by the `SYSUserID` which is `28` for that row.

Personally, I'd ditch `SYSUserID` if at all possible. Otherwise, you need to correct the code so that it looks for the right ID column at the right times (this will be a massive PITA in the future), or correct that record so that the `SYSUserID` and `SYSUserProfileID` match. Either of these should fix *this* problem, but changing that record **may** break other things.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem. I fixed it by simply changing the primary key in the Profile table from the SYSUserProfileID column to the SYSUserID column, which I need because it's tied to the user's login information. Thanks much for the help,